# What is the expected behaviour when `q()` is called, if q has been user-defined?

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, language-lawyer

The function `q()` terminates the current R session. But it is not a reserved word, so

```
q <- function(x) x + 1
```

is not an error. However, in RStudio calling `q(42)` starts a prompt asking me how to quit (as if `q` had never been defined), whereas `Rgui.exe` returns `43`, as I expected.

Typing `q` in the console returns `function(x) x + 1` the same in both RStudio and Rgui.exe

What should `q(42)` return?

Screenshot of RStudio console:

[image]

Comment: I do not get this behaviour on my RStudio (Version 0.99.1190 -- latest preview version). That is, redefining `q` gives me 43.

Comment: Not  reproducible for me either. A call to q(42) returns 43 in this case (irrespective of whether this is run in RStudio - I'm using v. 0.99.902 - or in an R shell). Try to type `q` without parentheses in the console to check if your function is defined in the global environment.

Comment: I am also using RStudio version  `0.99.902`

Comment: The question is not how to quit when `q` is in the global environment. I do think this is a bug in my version of RStudio; though the fact that @RHertel is using the same version doesn't support that hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry, I'm grateful for your comment. Typing `q` in the console returns the expected result in both RStudio and Rgui: `function(x) x + 1`.

Comment: Thanks for this information. In that case I don't understand why you observe this behavior. I'm mostly working on Linux where the problem doesn't occur. Now I tried to reproduce the situation on Windows 10 using RStudio v 0.99.902 and I can **confirm** this error. Probably you should submit a bug report.

Comment: OK. I've emailed a bug report (the github page doesn't seem to have issues). Thanks for helping to reproduce.